# How to set laravel custom validation message with laravel rules

Tags: php, laravel

Let me show first my code. Here is my controller function code

```
public function save(Request $request) {
    try {
        $this->validate($request, Venue::rules()); // Validation  Rules 
        $venue = Venue::saveOrUpdate($request);
        if($venue !== false) {
            if($request->get('continue', false)) {
                return redirect()->route('admin.venue.edit', ['id' => $venue->id])->with('success', trans('admin.venue.save_success'));
            } else {
                return redirect()->route('admin.venue.index')->with('success', trans('admin.venue.save_success'));
            }
        } else {
            return back()->with('error', "Unable to save venue")->withInput();
        }

    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        return back()->with('error', "Unable to save venue")->withInput();
    }
}
```

Here is my model function code

```
public static function rules($id = '') {
    return [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'logo' => 'required',
        'status' => 'required|string|in:' . implode(",", Venue::STATUSES),
        'venue_type_id' => 'required|string|not_in:0',
         'client_id' => 'required|string|not_in:0',
    ];
}
```

So now when i submit form validation show message. I want to change this message.How can i do this.

Let me show my form with validation message :
[image]

Comment: try FormRequest (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#form-request-validation) and refer the heading `Customizing The Error Messages`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may customize the `error messages` used by the `form request` by overriding the `messages()` method. Add custom `messages` on your `Venue` class as follows-

```
public static function messages($id = '') {
return [
    'name.required' => 'You must enter your name',
    'logo.required' => 'You must upload logo',
    'key.rules' => 'your messages'
];
```

And on your controller add `messages` as third `parameter` like-

```
$this->validate($request, Venue::rules(), Venue::messages());
```

Comment: quick question `'client_id' => 'required|string|not_in:0'` is id when i set ` 'client_id.required' => 'Select Client',`its not working.

Comment: try dd(Input::all()) before validation and see what you get as client_id

Comment: `"client_id" => "0"` gt this. when client not selected.

Comment: then its not empty surely, that's why is not having required validation error

Comment: is there any way to set that if id is 0 then count as null in custom message where we define name.required like client_id.required.somethin..like that ?

Comment: you can pass empty string from your view form

Answer (score 8):

You can custom the validation message by ,

Go to the     `resources->lang->en->validation.php`

and here you see,

```
'custom' => [
        'attribute-name' => [
            'rule-name' => 'custom-message',
        ],
    ],
```

Edit those as per your need.

Comment: is it possible to add new custome message on rules which i created on model.

Comment: Gt the answer.thanx

Answer (score 6):

This is the way I go about this and could serve as a guide. From your form, you've got basically 4 input fields and lets assume they are named **name, client, logo and venue_type**. The function in your controller that validates the form request can be like below:
N.B - you should put - 
**use Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;** - at the top of your class

```
public function validateFormRequest($request){
    try
    {

        //specify your custom message here
        $messages = [
          'required' => 'The :attribute field is required',
          'string'    => 'The :attribute must be text format',
          'file'    => 'The :attribute must be a file',
          'mimes' => 'Supported file format for :attribute are :mimes',
          'max'      => 'The :attribute must have a maximum length of :max',
        ];


        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
              'name' => 'required|string|max:75',
              'client' => 'required|string|max:75',
              'logo' => 'required|file|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif',
              'venue_type' => 'required|string',
          ], $messages);

        if($validator->fails()){ 
            // Validation Failed..log errors or Return Errors to view/blade
        } else{ 
            // Validation passed..Return true or positive info. i.e request can be saved
        }

    }catch (Exception $ex){
        //Log your errors or return some error message to your view/blade
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can add custom errors like this.

```
$validation->errors()->add('error_input', 'error text');

return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation);
```

or

```
return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors(['error_input'=> 'error text');
```

Comment: you can add this error to your validation and  
return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation);

Comment: can someone post editable code ? as i gt error `Undefined variable: validation`

Comment: so if i have a 15 fields in my form ..so all i need to set on return ?

Comment: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;



$validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'user_name' => 'required',
            'user_last_name' => 'required',
            'user_phone' => 'required',
            'user_email'  => 'required|email',
            'user_agreement'  => 'required',
            'address' => 'required',
            'quantity' => 'required|integer|min:1|max:1000',
        ]);

this is custom validator example you first  use this and then add your custom validator